# Find the Laplace transform of $f(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $t<5$} \\ t^2−10t+31, & \text{if $t\ge 5$} \\ \end{cases} $

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the Laplace transform of

$$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t<5$} \\
t^2−10t+31, & \text{if $t\ge 5$}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

$F(s)=$ ***_*__*_*__*_*___**?

Here is my work. I went wrong somewhere. Can someone tell me the correct answer

First, rewrite $t^2 - 10t + 31$ in powers of $t - 5$:
$$\begin{split}
  t^2 - 10t + 31
&= [(t - 5) + 5]^2 - 10 [(t - 5) + 5] + 31 \\
&= [(t - 5)^2 + 10(t - 5) + 25] - [10(t - 5) + 50] + 31 \\
&= (t - 5)^2 + 1.
\end{split}
$$

Hence,
$$\begin{split}
f(t) &= ((t - 5)^2 + 1) u(t - 5), \text{which implies}\\
F(s) &= \frac{2!}{s^3} + \frac{\exp(-5s)}{s} 
\end{split}$$

by the shifting theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simplification is wrong. Note that 
$(t-5)^2+1 = t^2 -10t + 26$ and you should have $t^2-10t+31$, so you need to use $(t-5)^2+6$ instead.

Comment: Isee. so what would the correct answer be now that we have the 6

Comment: (2!/s^3 + 6/s) e^(-5s) this is the correct anwer. Thanks so much